# How do I take first value of sub-array in an array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say my nested array is in the format [latitude, longitude] and the array that I want to input is [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]].

I want to return an array of only latitudes so
[10, 30, 50]
Now how do I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `.map()` method like so:

```js
var array = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]];

var result = array.map(item => item[0]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is how you do it, for loops are not.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the same result;

```
const arr = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]];
const latitudes=[];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   const arr1 = arr[i];

  latitudes.push(arr1[0]); 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Support in :** Chrome(yes) , Firefox(yes), IE5.5+ ,O(yes),Safari(yes)

```js
var arr = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]] ;
var i = 0 , res = [] ;

while (i < arr.length ) {
  res.push(arr[i][0]) ;
  i++ ;
}

console.log (res) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can also use destructuring & [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get it to this:

```js
var arr = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]];

var result = arr.map(([a]) => a)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` with `array#destructuring` to get the first index item from the individual array.

```js
var locations = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]],
    latitudes = locations.map(([latitude]) => latitude);
console.log(latitudes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) too.

```js
let obj = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]];

const newArr = obj.reduce((nArr, lat) => {
  nArr.push(lat[0]);
  return nArr;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a number of looping mechanisms to choose from.  The most straightforward is a `map` since you expect an array as a result.  Using destructuring assignment simplifies the naming, but there is more magic going on and it is ES6-heavy, so keep that in mind if cross-browser compliance is a concern.

```js
let log = console.log
let arr = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]]

// Destructuring Assignment
let ex1 = arr.map(([lat,long])=>lat) 
log('ex1:',ex1)

// Non-Destructuring
let ex2 = arr.map(set=>set[0])
log('ex2:',ex2)

// Reduce
let ex3 = arr.reduce((ar,val)=>(ar.push(val[0]),ar),[])
log('ex3:',ex3)
```

Of course you could get creative and flatten the array and use math to cherry-pick your values:

```js
let arr = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]]
let ex4 = arr.flat().filter((v,i)=>!(i%2))
console.log('ex4:',ex4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Using forEach:

```
let latLongs = [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]

let lats = []
latLongs.forEach(
    (latLong) => {
      lats.push(latLong[0])
    }
)

console.log(lats)
```